# Ajuda com forEach no jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Estou tentando fazer um if num arquivo jsp, mas não consigo imprimir todos os valores que estão na tabela produtos. Por algum motivo o meu código só imprime o primeiro produto e na tabela eu tenho 3 produtos.

```
            <c:forEach items="${products}"  var="product">
        <div class="w3-col l3 s4" style="width: 25rem;">
            <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="/w3images/" style="width:80%">
                ${product.productName}

            </div>
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h5 class="card-title">${product.productPrice}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${product.productDescription}</p>
                <input id="productId" name="productId" type="hidden" value="${product.productId}">
                <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black" >Bid</button>

                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
</c:forEach>
```

My backend:

```
    private ProductService productService = new ProductService();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String product_name = request.getParameter("userSearch");

        List<Product> productList = productService.searchProductName(product_name); //get product by name

        request.setAttribute("products", productList);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/userAds.jsp").forward(request, response);

        System.out.println(productList);


    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userSearch = request.getParameter("userSearch");


        List<Product> productList = productService.searchProductName(userSearch); //get product by name

        request.setAttribute("products", productList);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/userAds.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu forEach parece estar ok, será que o problema não está no backend?
Talvez  o seu objeto 'products' não esteja sendo preenchido com os três itens.

Faça um debug no seu código Java para checar isso, ou faça um dump do objeto no JSP assim:

```
<!--
  ${products}
-->
```

Acredito que isso vai mostrar  o conteúdo do objeto (chamando o toString) como comentário no html gerado,  assim você  pode verificar clicando em 'View  Source' no navegador.

Em todo caso, seria  interessante colocar o código backend para ajudar na análise.

Comment: Eu adicionei o meu backend na pergunta.  Se eu coloco products, dá erro e a página nem abre.

Comment: Legal, você chegou a colocar um debug na linha que chama productService.searchProductName() para ver se está retornando todos os produtos? Outra coisa que observei no seu código  é que você está usando um parâmetro da request chamando 'userSearch' para ser usado como 'nome de produto', isso está correto?